# Best method to authenticate that a user is actually a college student using gmail API in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, authentication

When I type in a .edu address into gmail.com it automatically takes me the CAS page for that specific university. Does anyone know how I can direct the user to that specific CAS page for the university given that he or she gives me the school that they go to in my Android or iOS application?

I need to authenticate that a student is actually in a university in my app, so this is the method I am thinking to use. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

A user possessing an email address on a university's domain is certainly a good indication that they have an affiliation with the school. If you're using Google's SSO service, you can let the service do the authentication (which in Google's case, means using their account chooser) and then block any accounts that don't come from approved domains.

A similar approach, albeit with potentially more flexibility, would be to use a service like Firebase and create your own username/password based authentication system. With Firebase, this isn't hard to do, and you'd be able to restrict sign-ups by using the email verification system. Part of your validation could be a check to make sure the email address used is on an approved domain.

Docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Comment: I was thinking to use the google OAUTH service but is there a tutorial on how I can get started with the SSO service?

Comment: In the link I provided there are lots of code samples. Many of those code samples include a link (in the bottom right hand corner of the code) to the file on github. Firebase doesn't have a very steep learning curve. Try out some of their samples and you'll be 80% of the way there.

Comment: How about the Google's SSO service? Do I need Firebase to use that?

Comment: No, you don't have to use Firebase. It is possible to just integrate directly: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: Ah yes that is exactly what I am using. Sorry for asking too much but how would I go about `block any accounts that don't come from approved domains`? Like for example if a student goes to universityA how would I know that the domain is UniversityA's domain or not?

Comment: Unfortunately I feel like you'd have to maintain a list. That's why something like Firebase might be a really great solution for you. You could use the database to store an approved list, use the Auth system to authenticate your users, and use other features, such as the Cloud Functions, to do additional server-based checks for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159020/discussion-between-hondaguy-and-toothyrel).

Answer (score 0):

I researched a little more and found out a solution to anyone who requires this specific use case:

1. Set up `GIDSignIn` instance in your mobile application using this link (For swift but there should be one for Android): https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift
2. Then on that `GIDSignIn` instance you can set the correct domain using the `hostedDomain` property on that `GIDSignIn` instance you created in step 1.